# Как из приложения на NodeJS зайти на сторонний сайт, который требует авторизации?

Tags: node.js, post, сессия, request

Требуется авторизоваться на сторонний сервер и получить доступ к контенту для авторизованных пользователей.

PhantomJS не подходит.

Я пробовал так:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var credentials = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://mysite.ru/login',
    headers: { 'content–type': 'application/x–www–form–urlencoded' },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error(' Login failed'));
        return;
    }

    request('http://mysite.ru/all', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Но на выходе выдает ХТМЛ код той же страницы логина.

Не прошу редактировать мой код, но быть может кто-то ткнет носом в правильный урок? Желательно в связке с PostMan - ом (чтобы можно было проанализировав стандартные запросы браузера и использовать их в своих запросах из приложения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать так:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
**var request = request.defaults({jar: true})**
var credentials = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://mysite.ru/login',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials),
        headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error(' Login  failed'));
        return;
    }

    request('http://mysite.ru/all', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ =  cheerio.load(body);

        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Но не понятно как управлять всеми полученными данными (как айди сессии и так далее) Если кто то может с этим помочь - помогите!)